# How to use Elasticsearch to perform a query that acts like the "join" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I have the following 2 *.csv files. And they have a common column called `CustomerID`.

Orders.csv

```
OrderID,CustomerID,OrderDate
10308,2,1996/9/18
10309,37,1996/9/19
10310,77,1996/9/20
```

Customers.csv

```
CustomerID,CustomerName,ContactName,Country,CustomerCreateDate
1,Alfreds Futterkiste,Maria Anders,Germany,2022/4/1
2,Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados,Ana Trujillo,Mexico,2022/5/3
3,Antonio Moreno Taquería,Antonio Moreno,Mexico,2022/4/23
```

I imported them to my elasticsearch as 2 indices (which are named as `index_customers`, and `index_orders`) using "Upload a file" integration.

[image]

Is it possible to use [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) to fetch the documents that contain `CustomerID=2` in the 2 indices?

Here's what I have tried:

```
GET index_*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "CustomerName": {
              "query": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "OrderID": {
              "query": "10308"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't return any matched data.

If you think of the 2 `*.csv` files as 2 tables in MySQL, this is what I want to query.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.CustomerName, Customers.ContactName, Customers.Country, Customers.CustomerCreateDate, Orders.OrderID,  Orders.OrderDate
FROM Customers 
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID WHERE Customers.CustomerID=2;
```

Is it possible to perform this kind of query in elasticsearch?

I've read [this document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html), but I haven't figured out how to use `nested`, `has_child`, and `has_parent` queries to implement what I want.

Comment: So, just out of the blue ... `Elasticsearch` and `Join` really are not made to work together.
It has a very limited support https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html

Comment: I've read that [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) before, and I'm wondering how to use `nested`, `has_child`, and `has_parent` queries to implement `join`.

Comment: Nested could make sense, but would need to be done pior to ingest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

Elasticsearch is not made for `Join` queries.

## Workaround

```json
GET 73048773_*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "CustomerID": 2
    }
  }
  ,
  "_source": ["CustomerName", "OrderID"]
}
```

Should give you:

```json
{
 ...
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "73048773_customer",
        "_id": "_Rr5GoIBc5_pveXGq7kJ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "CustomerName": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "73048773_order",
        "_id": "-Rr5GoIBc5_pveXGq7kJ",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "OrderID": 10308
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your solution. Is it possible to exclude a few fields with this workaround?
For example, I may only want to display `CustomerName` and `OrderID`.

Comment: Sure it is possible look at the update.